# I need to match special character, how can I write query to get the required output?

Tags: sql

I want mail which is common at supplier's and customer's tables only, I don't
want emails that don't match in customer's table with the supplier's mail. Unfortunately,
we don't have similar IDs to join so if possible can we join with the mail only,
if not then we can consider common IDs and join them.

following tables for your reference and output that I want
[image: CUSTOMER TABLE] [image: SUPPLIER TABLE][image: THE OUTPUT THAT I WANT FROM SUPPLIER TABLE]

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: What is your database environment? My answer below was for SQL Server. Other DBMSs may have a different solution.

Comment: There's also the option to use GitHub Markdown tables to show us your tables: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution is to normalize your database design to not store multiple values in the same column. However, I expect that is water under the bridge.

Given the data that you have, you can use `STRING_SPLIT()` to separate the emails from the `SUPPLIERS` table and then join with `CUSTOMERS`.

```
SELECT S.ID, C.EMAIL
FROM SUPPLIERS S
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT value AS EMAIL
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(S.EMAIL, ',')
) E
JOIN CUSTOMERS C ON C.EMAIL = E.EMAIL
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bqdUIzJU)

If your data may have any spaces mixed in, you may need to add `TRIM()` to the `STRING_SPLIT()` result - `SELECT TRIM(value) AS EMAIL`.

Comment: STRING_SPLIT is a product specific function. Which dbms is this for?

Comment: @jarlh The above is for SQL Server. The original post tagged sql-server plus several others that I didn't notice at the time. A_horse_with_no_name removed all of the DBMS-specific  tags shortly afterwards. Raaj has not yet responded to the request to identify which DBMS applies.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select CC.ID, CC.email from
    (
            SELECT        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS AID,a.*
            FROM           Suppliers a
    ) as AA

    left outer join 
    (
            Select BB.* from
            (
                    SELECT        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS BID,b.*
                    FROM           Customers b
            ) as BB
    ) as CC
    on AA.AID = CC.BID
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/PsMX54Te

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/K-_HX-om